# How to check FirstName and LastName exist in Database in MVC MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to check users with FirstName and LastName exist in Database?

I have this code in Model:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
[DisplayName("FirstName")]
[Remote("IsPatnikExists", "patnici")]
public string firstname { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
[DisplayName("LastName")]
[Remote("IsPatnikExists", "patnici", ErrorMessage = "Ова име и презиме веќе постои.")]
public string LastName{ get; set; }
```

and this code is in Controller where check:

```
public JsonResult IsPatnikExists(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    return Json(!db.tbl_patnici.Any(x => x.firstname == firstname) && !db.tbl_patnici.Any(x => x.lastname == lastname), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How to check Combination in Database?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to check in single query with `&&`, currently you are checking separately, so change it to be like :

```
return Json(!db.tbl_patnici
                .Any(x => x.firstname == firstname && x.lastname == lastname),
             JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Yes but values check separately and if send FirstName, is ok, then when will sent LastName , automaticaly clear Firstname and not keep, then check just LastName.

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean by that

Comment: This is Json, result get Back When i give value, and When i Put Firstname, Then Go and put LastName after click anywhere i need to give message back. Ex. Like this: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/Content/images/Uploadedbyauthors/wlw/e349262d0d85_1411C/image_6.png but here check just one cell.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. I have just added the following in the model:
    [Remote("IsPatnikExists", "patnici", AdditionalFields = "firstname", ErrorMessage = "Ова име и презиме веќе постои.")]

In the remote i have added **AdditionalFields = "firstname"**